# Optimise MySQL on VPS (2 CPUs & 3 GB RAM) with WP MU

Tags: mysql, mysqltuner, wordpress

I have a vps server with os centos 6.7 64x, 2 cpu's and 3gb ram, and I use it exclusively for a WP MU (Memory limit: 512 MByte/Memory usage: 53.97 MByte).

I use mostly myisam and have about 30 subsites, most of them are blogs and there some e-shops. The visits in all of these sites everydays is about 100 to 250 people on each site. And sometimes, some sites might 400 to 800 visits. I have added the plugin w3tc and stil I feel that it goes slow for the guests and for the logged in users too.

How can I understand how much memory and cpu I need everytime so I won't have any problems and what else do you need so I can give you a better image of my server?

My nano /etc/my.cnf

```
[myisamchk]
read_buffer=16M
key_buffer=32M
write_buffer=16M
sort_buffer=32M
[mysqld_safe]
open_files_limit=8192
log-error="/var/log/mysqld.log"
pid-file="/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid"
[mysqld]
slow-query-log=1
slow-query-log-file="/var/log/mysql/slow.log"
long_query_time=4
log_queries_not_using_indexes=1
local-infile=0
join_buffer_size=10M
connect_timeout=10
read_buffer_size=1M
key_buffer=16M
key_buffer_size=70M
# old_passwords=1
max_allowed_packet=268435456
interactive_timeout=25
max_connect_errors=10
max_connections=256
wait_timeout=1000
query_cache_size=0
query_cache_type=OFF
user=mysql
thread_cache_size=286
sort_buffer_size=10M
tmp_table_size=256M
max_heap_table_size=256M
table_open_cache=500
query_cache_limit=128M
socket="/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock"
myisam_sort_buffer_size=32M
datadir="/var/lib/mysql"
default-storage-engine=MyISAM
innodb_file_per_table=1
innodb_buffer_pool_size=134217728
open_files_limit=10000
[isamchk]
read_buffer=16M
key_buffer=32M
write_buffer=16M
sort_buffer=32M
[mysqlhotcopy]
skip-networking
interactive-timeout
```

And this results of MySQLTuner

```
 >>  MySQLTuner 1.6.1 - Major Hayden <major@mhtx.net>
 >>  Bug reports, feature requests, and downloads at http://mysqltuner.com/
 >>  Run with '--help' for additional options and output filtering
[--] Skipped version check for MySQLTuner script
[OK] Currently running supported MySQL version 10.0.22-MariaDB-log
[OK] Operating on 64-bit architecture

-------- Storage Engine Statistics -------------------------------------------
[--] Status: +ARCHIVE +Aria +BLACKHOLE +CSV +FEDERATED +InnoDB +MRG_MyISAM
[--] Data in MyISAM tables: 501M (Tables: 869)
[--] Data in InnoDB tables: 656K (Tables: 16)
[!!] Total fragmented tables: 37

-------- Security Recommendations  -------------------------------------------
[OK] There are no anonymous accounts for any database users
[OK] All database users have passwords assigned
[--] There are 605 basic passwords in the list.

-------- Performance Metrics -------------------------------------------------
[--] Up for: 23h 28m 37s (1M q [12.900 qps], 36K conn, TX: 42B, RX: 1B)
[--] Reads / Writes: 82% / 18%
[--] Binary logging is disabled
[--] Total buffers: 598.0M global + 21.5M per thread (256 max threads)
[OK] Maximum reached memory usage: 1.0G (33.48% of installed RAM)
[!!] Maximum possible memory usage: 6.0G (198.89% of installed RAM)
[!!] Slow queries: 7% (86K/1M)
[OK] Highest usage of available connections: 7% (20/256)
[OK] Aborted connections: 0.18%  (65/36559)
[!!] Query cache is disabled
[OK] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 0% (0 temp sorts / 143K sorts)
[!!] Joins performed without indexes: 324
[!!] Temporary tables created on disk: 43% (37K on disk / 87K total)
[OK] Thread cache hit rate: 99% (20 created / 36K connections)
[!!] Table cache hit rate: 2% (500 open / 23K opened)
[OK] Open file limit used: 12% (998/8K)
[OK] Table locks acquired immediately: 99% (1M immediate / 1M locks)

-------- MyISAM Metrics -----------------------------------------------------
[!!] Key buffer used: 18.8% (13M used / 73M cache)
[OK] Key buffer size / total MyISAM indexes: 70.0M/145.8M
[OK] Read Key buffer hit rate: 99.4% (23M cached / 131K reads)
[!!] Write Key buffer hit rate: 30.6% (347K cached / 241K writes)

-------- InnoDB Metrics -----------------------------------------------------
[--] InnoDB is enabled.
[OK] InnoDB buffer pool / data size: 128.0M/656.0K
[!!] InnoDB buffer pool <= 1G and innodb_buffer_pool_instances(!=1).
[!!] InnoDB Used buffer: 6.36% (521 used/ 8191 total)
[OK] InnoDB Read buffer efficiency: 97.13% (17216 hits/ 17724 total)
[!!] InnoDB Write buffer efficiency: 0.00% (0 hits/ 1 total)
[OK] InnoDB log waits: 0.00% (0 waits / 21 writes)

-------- AriaDB Metrics -----------------------------------------------------
[--] AriaDB is disabled.

-------- Replication Metrics -------------------------------------------------
[--] No replication slave(s) for this server.
[--] This is a standalone server..

-------- Recommendations -----------------------------------------------------
General recommendations:
    Run OPTIMIZE TABLE to defragment tables for better performance
    MySQL started within last 24 hours - recommendations may be inaccurate
    Reduce your overall MySQL memory footprint for system stability
    Adjust your join queries to always utilize indexes
    Temporary table size is already large - reduce result set size
    Reduce your SELECT DISTINCT queries without LIMIT clauses
    Increase table_open_cache gradually to avoid file descriptor limits
    Read this before increasing table_open_cache over 64: http://bit.ly/1mi7c4C
    Beware that open_files_limit (8192) variable
    should be greater than table_open_cache ( 500)
Variables to adjust:
  *** MySQL's maximum memory usage is dangerously high ***
  *** Add RAM before increasing MySQL buffer variables ***
    query_cache_size (>= 8M)
    join_buffer_size (> 10.0M, or always use indexes with joins)
    table_open_cache (> 500)
    innodb_buffer_pool_instances (=1)
```

When it says "Add RAM before increasing MySQL buffer variables", what do I have to do exactly?

My tail -n 100 /var/log/mysql-slow-queries.log

```
tail: cannot open `/var/log/mysql-slow-queries.log' for reading: No such file or directory
```

My tail -n 100 /var/log/mysqld.log (On 0:03:45 and after I gives me data that belong on ip's and sites of mys server. How is this possible?)

```
160102 19:22:19 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
160102 19:22:19 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.26-74.0 started; log sequence number 27983072465
160102 19:22:19 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
160102 19:22:19 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
160102 19:22:19 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '10.0.22-MariaDB-log'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MariaDB Server
160102 21:13:47 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Normal shutdown

160102 21:13:47 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
160102 21:13:47 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
160102 21:13:47 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
160102 21:13:49 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 27983072475
160102 21:13:49 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

160102 21:13:49 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/lib/mysql/server.mywebsite.com.com.pid ended
160102 21:13:50 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
160102 21:13:50 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 10.0.22-MariaDB-log) starting as process 2670 ...
160102 21:13:50 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
160102 21:13:50 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
160102 21:13:50 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
160102 21:13:50 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
160102 21:13:50 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
160102 21:13:50 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
160102 21:13:50 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
160102 21:13:50 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
160102 21:13:50 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
160102 21:13:50 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
160102 21:13:50 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
160102 21:13:50 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
160102 21:13:50 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.26-74.0 started; log sequence number 27983072475
160102 21:13:50 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
160102 21:13:50 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
160102 21:13:50 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '10.0.22-MariaDB-log'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MariaDB Server
160102 23:13:09 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Normal shutdown

160102 23:13:09 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
160102 23:13:09 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
160102 23:13:09 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
160102 23:13:11 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 27983072485
160102 23:13:11 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

160102 23:13:11 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/lib/mysql/server.mywebsite.com.pid ended
160102 23:13:11 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
160102 23:13:11 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 10.0.22-MariaDB-log) starting as process 8751 ...
160102 23:13:11 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
160102 23:13:11 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
160102 23:13:11 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
160102 23:13:11 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
160102 23:13:11 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
160102 23:13:11 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
160102 23:13:11 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
160102 23:13:11 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
160102 23:13:11 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
160102 23:13:11 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
160102 23:13:11 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
160102 23:13:11 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
160102 23:13:11 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.26-74.0 started; log sequence number 27983072485
160102 23:13:11 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
160102 23:13:11 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
160102 23:13:11 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '10.0.22-MariaDB-log'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MariaDB Server
160102 23:16:09 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Normal shutdown

160102 23:16:09 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
160102 23:16:09 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
160102 23:16:09 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
160102 23:16:11 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 27983072495
160102 23:16:11 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

160102 23:16:11 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/lib/mysql/server.mywebsite.com.pid ended
160102 23:16:11 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
160102 23:16:11 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 10.0.22-MariaDB-log) starting as process 10571 ...
160102 23:16:11 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
160102 23:16:11 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
160102 23:16:11 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
160102 23:16:11 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
160102 23:16:11 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
160102 23:16:11 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
160102 23:16:11 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
160102 23:16:11 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
160102 23:16:11 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
160102 23:16:11 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
160102 23:16:11 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
160102 23:16:11 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
160102 23:16:11 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.26-74.0 started; log sequence number 27983072495
160102 23:16:11 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
160102 23:16:11 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
160102 23:16:11 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '10.0.22-MariaDB-log'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MariaDB Server
160103  0:03:45 [Warning] IP address '222.186.30.119' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
160103  4:45:12 [Warning] IP address '222.186.50.221' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
160103  8:02:49 [Warning] IP address '123.57.67.126' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
160103 10:22:34 [Warning] Hostname 'mx.campprice.com' does not resolve to '216.99.158.156'.
160103 10:22:34 [Note] Hostname 'mx.campprice.com' has the following IP addresses:
160103 10:22:34 [Note]  - 5.2.16.155
160103 11:37:24 [Warning] IP address '1.93.1.91' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
160103 14:38:25 [Warning] IP address '171.92.207.61' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
160103 15:06:41 [Warning] IP address '221.231.139.150' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
160103 16:41:46 [Warning] IP address '5.39.222.253' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
```

My [tail -n 100 /var/log/mysql/slow.log](http://pastebin.com/9BeKbQtn)

My ls -l /var/lib/mysql

```
   total 125260
drwxr-x--x 16 mysql mysql     4096 Dec 29 03:27 ./
drwxr-xr-x 20 root  root      4096 Dec 29 03:12 ../
drwx------  2 mysql mysql    57344 Dec 14 19:15 tsimis_vemal/
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql    16384 Dec 28 01:49 aria_log.00000001
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql       52 Dec 28 01:49 aria_log_control
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql       56 Dec 11 15:23 auto.cnf
drwx------  2 mysql mysql     4096 Dec  7 23:46 cphulkd/
drwx------  2 mysql mysql     4096 Dec 28 05:30 eximstats/
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql 27262976 Dec 28 20:43 ibdata1
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql 50331648 Dec 28 20:43 ib_logfile0
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql 50331648 Dec 11 15:23 ib_logfile1
drwx------  2 mysql mysql     4096 Dec  7 23:46 tsarmil_wordpress/
drwx------  2 mysql mysql     4096 Dec  7 23:46 leechprotect/
drwx------  2 mysql mysql     4096 Dec  7 23:46 modsec/
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql        0 Dec 11 15:25 multi-master.info
drwx--x--x  2 mysql mysql     4096 Dec 11 15:25 mysql/
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql        0 Nov 21 22:17 mysql-bin.index
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql    18229 Nov 21 22:18 mysql-error.log
srwxrwxrwx  1 mysql mysql        0 Dec 28 01:49 mysql.sock=
-rw-r--r--  1 mysql mysql       15 Dec 11 15:25 mysql_upgrade_info
drwx------  2 mysql mysql     4096 Dec 11 15:25 performance_schema/
drwx------  2 mysql mysql     4096 Dec  7 23:46 roundcube/
-rw-r--r--  1 mysql mysql     1021 Dec 11 15:24 RPM_UPGRADE_HISTORY
-rw-r--r--  1 mysql mysql      526 Dec 11 15:24 RPM_UPGRADE_MARKER-LAST
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql    80432 Nov 15 13:35 server.mydomain.com.err
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql        5 Dec 28 01:49 server.mydomain.com.pid
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql        0 Nov 21 01:33 slow.log
drwx------  2 mysql mysql    36864 Dec 28 01:41 dumdum_dbsp/
drwx------  2 mysql mysql    36864 Dec 23 00:28 dumdum_demoplayer/
drwx------  2 mysql mysql     4096 Dec 10 01:21 dumdum_mudemodb/
drwx------  2 mysql mysql     4096 Dec  7 23:46 dumdum_ttvelmor/
drwx------  2 mysql mysql     4096 Dec 15 03:27 whmxfer/
```

My top

```
top - 22:53:01 up 5 days, 18:39,  1 user,  load average: 1.07, 0.85, 0.59
Tasks:  72 total,   2 running,  67 sleeping,   0 stopped,   3 zombie
Cpu(s): 22.3%us,  1.5%sy,  0.0%ni, 76.2%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   3145728k total,  2348472k used,   797256k free,        0k buffers
Swap:  3145728k total,   175068k used,  2970660k free,  2097268k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
31449 account1  20   0  304m 129m  74m R 32.3  4.2   1:58.94 php
32640 account1  20   0  314m 135m  72m S 10.3  4.4   0:17.33 php
10571 mysql     20   0  988m 105m 8112 S  1.0  3.4  31:31.90 mysqld
  582 root      20   0 99800 4340 3256 S  0.3  0.1   0:00.08 sshd
 1111 root      20   0  112m  440  360 S  0.3  0.0   0:01.20 crond
 1138 root      20   0  108m  752  648 S  0.3  0.0   0:07.40 varnishd
23350 nobody    20   0 63572 4404 2104 S  0.3  0.1   0:00.70 httpd
25143 nobody    20   0 63564 4396 2112 S  0.3  0.1   0:00.45 httpd
    1 root      20   0 19236  984  844 S  0.0  0.0   0:01.97 init
    2 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kthreadd/1227
    3 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 khelper/1227
  147 root      16  -4 10648  352  348 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 udevd
  451 dovecot   20   0 29576 2228 1672 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.01 auth
  554 root      20   0     0    0    0 Z  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 cpsrvd (SSL) -  <defunct>
  555 root      20   0     0    0    0 Z  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 cpsrvd (SSL) -  <defunct>
  583 sshd      20   0 67784 1652  848 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 sshd
  595 root      20   0 67784 3256 2500 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 sshd
  596 sshd      20   0 67784 1560  804 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 sshd
  728 root      20   0  179m 4380  800 S  0.0  0.1   0:24.25 rsyslogd
  749 named     20   0  233m 3388 1548 S  0.0  0.1   0:16.58 named
  767 nscd      20   0  941m 1420  984 S  0.0  0.0   0:36.59 nscd
  792 root      20   0 64336  560  460 S  0.0  0.0   0:09.77 sshd
  802 root      20   0 20040  364  360 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 xinetd
 1034 root      20   0 18212  844  676 S  0.0  0.0   0:01.74 dovecot
 1039 dovenull  20   0 42644 2748 2544 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.25 pop3-login
 1040 dovenull  20   0 42648 3028 2592 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.43 imap-login
 1041 dovecot   20   0 13472  916  816 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.52 anvil
 1042 root      20   0 13608 1032  872 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.89 log
 1044 dovenull  20   0 42740 2812 2580 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.70 pop3-login
 1045 dovenull  20   0 42788 3056 2620 S  0.0  0.1   0:01.52 imap-login
 1049 root      20   0 14636 1764  948 S  0.0  0.1   0:01.88 config
 1054 root      20   0 66412  284  280 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 saslauthd
 1056 root      20   0 66412   32   28 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 saslauthd
 1068 mailnull  20   0 70564 2536 2396 S  0.0  0.1   0:01.06 exim
 1077 root      20   0  194m 7072 2752 S  0.0  0.2   0:59.42 /usr/local/cpan
 1089 root      20   0 62448 5596 4212 S  0.0  0.2   0:10.45 httpd
 1098 root      20   0  133m 1432 1364 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.50 pure-ftpd
 1100 root      20   0  132m 1352 1304 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.44 pure-authd
 1183 root      20   0 19428  384  364 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 atd
 1540 root      20   0  105m 3092 1120 S  0.0  0.1   0:06.81 cpsrvd (SSL) -
 1546 root      20   0 32692 1680 1424 S  0.0  0.1   0:01.13 queueprocd - wa
 1562 root      20   0 78132 6704 1672 S  0.0  0.2   1:11.63 tailwatchd
 1577 root      20   0 34240 2512 1780 S  0.0  0.1   0:47.76 cPhulkd - proce
 1606 root      20   0  119m 1844  664 S  0.0  0.1   0:02.48 cpdavd - accept
 1617 root      38  18 23664 1684 1128 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.94 cpanellogd - sl
 1639 nobody    20   0  321m  732  556 S  0.0  0.0   0:08.56 memcached
 1646 root      20   0  4068  496  492 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 mingetty
 1647 root      20   0  4068  496  492 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 mingetty
 7355 root      20   0  219m  75m 3424 S  0.0  2.4   0:42.96 spamd child
10391 root      20   0  9416 1120 1116 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 mysqld_safe
20373 root      20   0 13468 1124  932 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ssl-params
23347 root      20   0 76528  11m 2896 S  0.0  0.4   0:00.09 leechprotect
23348 nobody    20   0 62584 2296  760 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.06 httpd
```

Answer (score 1):

> [!!] Query cache efficiency: 19.9% (71K cached / 357K selects)
>   [!!] Query cache prunes per day: 250428

Turn off the Query cache:

```
query_cache_type = OFF
query_cache_size = 0
```

> [!!] Table cache hit rate: 2% (200 open / 8K opened)

How many tables do you have?  Sounds like more than 200??  This is sometimes a sign of a bad schema design; please explain why so many.

Meanwhile, change

```
table_open_cache = 500
```

The rest of the `[!!]` are bogus; ignore them.

The only Recommendation of note is

> MySQL started within last 24 hours - recommendations may be inaccurate

You do seem to have slow queries.  So, use pt-query-digest to summarize `/var/log/mysql-slow-queries.log`.  Come back to us (in a separate thread) with the two worst queries, together with

```
    SHOW CREATE TABLE
    EXPLAIN SELECT ...
```

If (when) your dataset grows to, say, twice its current size, some buffer settings should be re-investigated.

Executive summary:

- Increase `table_open_cache`
- Look into improving the 'slow' queries.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40575/discussion-on-answer-by-rick-james-optimise-mysql-on-vps-2-cpus-3-gb-ram-wit).